# PrimeFaces dialogue showing the wrong information

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu, primefaces, datatable, javabeans

I have a page with 2 dropdown lists that fill a data-table (depending on the choice made in the dropdown lists). The data table contains check-boxes for selecting multiple lines and then opening a dialogue that shows information based on the selected lines. the problem is: the first time I click on the button to open the dialogue it's empty, when I change the content of the dropdown lists and open the dialogue it will show the information of the previous selection not the one i just made and it'll stay that way until i change the dropdown list and so on... the dialogue always shows the information of the previous selection before changing the choice made in the dropdown list.

the page:

```
        <h:form id="form">
    <f:view>

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
    <p:layout style="min-width:300px;min-height:200px;" id="layout">
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="200" minSize="40" maxSize="300">
        <!-- _______________________________________start drop down________________________________________________________ -->
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

                <p:selectOneMenu id="Item" value="#{ThemeBean.idItem}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select un Item " itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ItemBean.listItemsUser}" var="utilisateur" />
                    <p:ajax listener="#{ThemeBean.handleCityChange}" update="suburbs" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="suburbs" value="#{ReponseBean.idTheme}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select un Theme" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ThemeBean.suburbs}" />
                    <p:ajax listener="#{ReponseBean.handleCityChange_Ecart}" update=":form:dropArea" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:separator />
        </p:layoutUnit>
    <!-- _______________________________________end drop down________________________________________________________ -->
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">

            <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
                <p:dataTable id="dt1" var="car"
                    value="#{ReponseBean.listPartheme_ecart}"
                    rendered="#{not empty ReponseBean.listPartheme_ecart}"
                    rowKey="#{car.id}" editable="true"
                    selection="#{EcartBean.selectedCars}">

                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />
                    <p:column headerText="Questions">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.q1.text}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Reponse">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.rep}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="Ajouter Ecart" icon="ui-icon-search"
                            update=":form:multiDialog :form:displayMulti" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show()"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
                <!-- ________________________________________dialogue________________________________________________ -->
                <p:dialog id="multiDialog" header="Ajout Ecart" widgetVar="multiCarDialog" height="300" showEffect="fade">
                    <p:dataList id="displayMulti" value="#{EcartBean.selectedCars}" var="selectedCare">
                        #{selectedCare.q1.text} (#{selectedCare.rep})
                    </p:dataList>
                    <p:messages />
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

                        <h:outputLabel value="Niveau Ecart" />

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="idUtilisateur" value="#{EcartBean.idNiveauAudit}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{NiveauEcartBean.listNiveauSelect}"  var="nivecart" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:message for="idUtilisateur" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Constatation" id="Constatation" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{EcartBean.consta}" />
                        <p:message for="Constatation" />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Ajouter" id="ViewButton" action="#{EcartBean.save}"
                            oncomplete="multiCarDialog.hide();">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:dialog>

            </p:outputPanel>

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>

    </f:view>
    </h:form>
```

the methode ThemeBean.handleCityChange :

```
    public void handleCityChange() {

    qu = respQue.lister_Ques(idItem);

    if (qu != null) {
        List<SelectItem> listuti = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        List<Theme> list = resp.lister_Par_Thme(qu.getId());
        for (Theme p : list) {
            listuti.add(new SelectItem(p.getId(), p.getLibelle()));
        }
        this.setSuburbs(listuti);

    } else {
        System.out.println("erreur");
    }

}
```

ReponseBean.handleCityChange_Ecart :

```
    public void handleCityChange_Ecart() {

    listPartheme_ecart= new ArrayList<Reponse>();
    System.out.println("taiile avant "+listPartheme_ecart.size());
    List<Reponse> lr = respQ.findByTheme_ecart(idTheme);
    System.out.println(idTheme);
    for (int i = 0; i < lr.size(); i++) {
        if (lr.get(i).getAudit().getId() == aud.getId())
            listPartheme_ecart.add(lr.get(i));
    }

}
```

I should mention that in the console i see the write information when i open the dialogue, it just doesn't show write away on the dialogue.
thank you for your time and help.

I am updating this post to say that i finaly solved the probleme of filling the popup
i put the dialogue in a new form like this:

```
        </h:form>
    <!-- ________________________________________dialogue________________________________________________ -->
    <h:form id="hh" >
    <p:dialog id="multiDialog" header="Ajout Ecart" widgetVar="multiCarDialog" height="300" showEffect="fade">

        <p:dataList id="displayMulti" value="#{EcartBean.selectedCars}" var="selectedCare">
            #{selectedCare.q1.text} (#{selectedCare.rep})
        </p:dataList>
        <p:messages />

            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

                <h:outputLabel value="Niveau Ecart" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="idUtilisateur" value="#{EcartBean.idNiveauAudit}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{NiveauEcartBean.listNiveauSelect}"  var="nivecart" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:message for="idUtilisateur" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Constatation" id="Constatation" />

                <h:inputText value="#{EcartBean.consta}" />
                <p:message for="Constatation" />

                <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Ajouter" action="#{EcartBean.save}"  id="ViewButton" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.hide();" />

            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

i have now one little probleme: the commandButton in the dialogue does not fire the methode save i have tried

```
<p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Ajouter" action="#{EcartBean.save}"  id="ViewButton" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.hide();" />
```

and

```
<p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Ajouter" actionListener="#{EcartBean.save}"  id="ViewButton" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.hide();" />
```

and

```
<p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Ajouter" id="ViewButton" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.hide();" >
                <f:actionListener  binding="#{EcartBean.save}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
```

but nothing :( . where have gone wrong?

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation of [`<p:ajax>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/ajax.html), `listener` is triggered only on partial request which I don't see happening in the code that you pasted. Use `event="valueChange"` to trigger a partial request which would result the current update to be shown in dialog.

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{ThemeBean.handleCityChange}" update="suburbs" /> 

<p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{ReponseBean.handleCityChange_Ecart}" update=":form:dropArea" />
```

Comment: but their is no update attribut in p:selectOneMenu and their for i can't fill the second dropdown!

Comment: I get the problem now. Updating the answer

Comment: :( it's not that either, i  still get the datatable to show the lines but the popup is one step behind!

Comment: The `event="valueChange"` is **already the default**. It's unnecessary to repeat the defaults.

Comment: okey but that is not the issue anymore :). i have updated the probleme